# When inserting a new row, must I include the columns that are null in the query?

Tags: mysql

For example, say I have a table with 10 columns in it, but I have them all defaulting to null and when I want to insert a row I only want to insert 5 values into it. Do I need to include the columns that are defaulting to null in my query when inserting a new row, or can I exclude them and just specify values for the columns I want to put values in?

Comment: If a column has a default value set, you don't need to specify it. That's why columns that aren't necessary are usually defaulted to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needn't type each and every column.
You may specify the columns you wish to insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ('foo');
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

---

If you were to leave out the column list, then you'd need to enter a value for all columns:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('foo',NULL,NULL,...);
                   ^ no column list, must specify a value for all columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put specify only the columns in which you have data to insert (given that you comply with NOT NULL restrictions), and in the order that you want.